# What is the apt-get equivalent of this command?

Tags: apt

What is the apt-get equivalent of the following command?

```
aptitude -r install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') <package name>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') <package name>
```

For the record, this just installs the linux headers (likely, linux-headers-generic) and any additional packages you specify.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does `-r` mean as in `aptitude -r`?

Comment: It installs any packages listed as "Recommends" as well (it treats them like dependencies). It's default in `apt-get`, not sure about `aptitude`.